# JavaScript Оператор return

Tags: javascript, функции, return

Задача: вернуть средний символ слова. Если длина слова нечетна, верните средний символ. Если длина слова четная, верните средние 2 символа.

```
function getMiddle(s){
    var even, odd, centerLetter,arrLetter;
    (s.length%2==0) ?  (centerLetter = (Math.round(s.length/2))) : (centerLetter = (Math.round(s.length/2))-1) ;
    arrLetter = s.split("");
    (s.length%2==0) ? (console.log( arrLetter[centerLetter-1] + arrLetter[centerLetter] )) :(console.log(arrLetter[centerLetter]));
}
getMiddle("test"); //es
getMiddle("testing");//t
getMiddle("middle");//dd
getMiddle("A");//A
```

Вопрос: Я написал код который вывод в консоль ответ, как мне переписать код чтобы он возвращял функции через return?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getMiddle(s) {
  return !(s.length % 2) ? s.substr(s.length / 2 - 1, 2) : s[Math.round(s.length / 2) - 1];
}

console.log(getMiddle('test'))
console.log(getMiddle('testing'))
console.log(getMiddle('middle'))
console.log(getMiddle('A'))
```

**Обновлено**
Более короткий способ (спасибо [@Regent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183458/regent), *см. комментарии к посту*)

```js
function getMiddle(s) {
  return s.substr((s.length - 1) / 2, 2 - s.length % 2);
}

console.log(getMiddle('test'))
console.log(getMiddle('testing'))
console.log(getMiddle('middle'))
console.log(getMiddle('A'))
```

Comment: Можно покороче: `return s.substr(Math.floor((s.length - 1) / 2), 2 - s.length % 2);`

Comment: @Regent, спасибо! Единственное, на что хотел бы обратить ваше внимание - _Math.floor_ в данном случае будет лишним, так как _substr_ сам по себе оперирует только целочисленными значениями, а потому он попросту отбросит дробную часть самостоятельно.

Comment: На MDN-е я тогда упоминания использования `floor` не нашел, поэтому оставил его. Сейчас открыл спецификацию ECMAScript 2015 - там это есть. В принципе, явное указание в коде `floor` лучше с точки зрения понимания кода, но, согласен, действительно необязательно

Comment: __!(s.length % 2) ? s.substr(s.length / 2 - 1, 2) : s[Math.round(s.length / 2) - 1]__ зачем такой короткий запись сделал бы еще длинне.И самое главное что мне оч. понравилось имя переменной одна буква отлично так держать очень читаемо очень

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов: заменить тернарные оператор на `if` и в этом случае достаточно заменить `console.log` на `return`

```js
function getMiddle(s) {
  var even, odd, centerLetter, arrLetter;
  if (s.length % 2 == 0) {
    centerLetter = (Math.round(s.length / 2));
  } else {
    centerLetter = (Math.round(s.length / 2)) - 1;
  }
  arrLetter = s.split("");
  if (s.length % 2 == 0) {
    return arrLetter[centerLetter - 1] + arrLetter[centerLetter];
  } else {
    return arrLetter[centerLetter];
  }
}
console.log(getMiddle("test")); //es
console.log(getMiddle("testing")); //t
console.log(getMiddle("middle")); //dd
console.log(getMiddle("A")); //A
```

Либо использовать непосредственные результаты тернарного оператора:

```js
function getMiddle(s) {
  var even, odd, centerLetter, arrLetter;
  centerLetter = (s.length % 2 == 0) ? Math.round(s.length / 2) : ((Math.round(s.length / 2)) - 1);
  return (s.length % 2 == 0) ? (s[centerLetter - 1] + s[centerLetter]) : (s[centerLetter]);
}
console.log(getMiddle("test")); //es
console.log(getMiddle("testing")); //t
console.log(getMiddle("middle")); //dd
console.log(getMiddle("A")); //A
```

Comment: `Math.round` при делении четного числа на два - это копипаст из вопроса или действительно что-то может пойти не так?

Comment: @Regent, да, это копипаст, не вглядывался в реализацию, вроде тесты правильные результаты дают, значит норм :)

Answer (score 0):

В конце функций в return = centerLetter;

- Или в место присвоения centerLetter поставь return

Comment: `centerLetter` = это _индекс_ среднего символа, а не сам символ